# C: library for parsing configuration files and command line

Tags: c, parsing, configuration

I'm looking for some library with support for strict set of options (so non-existent options couldn't be set in config file) and possibility to also parse command line to override options from config file. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you found yourself, e.g. with Google or similar?

Comment: I've found tonns of libraries, but none of them supports command line argument overriding. In other case I wouldn't ask.

Comment: What is problem to use two libraries?

Comment: combining results also more dependencies

Answer (score 1):

For command line, there is getopt or [plentiful](http://libhx.sf.net/) [of](http://freecode.com/projects/popt/) [code](http://caca.zoy.org/browser/libcaca/trunk/caca/getopt.c), some with more, some with less strange APIs, some in the form of open-codedness like getopt, others in table form with or without callback ability. As for config file, there is (lib)augeas if you need support for almost arbitrary formats.

Comment: I need library able to parse both: config files and command line. Not just config files. There are plenty of such libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use LGPL stuff in your project, there's http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/, which appears, according to the docs, to have support in the API for setting values after a file has been parsed.

Comment: I know that and libconfuse has it too, but I don't want to do that manually. IMHO thats a really common task so there should be some ready solutions.

Comment: You don't want to have to take argv and place it into a library's data manually?

Comment: No, I don't. Also libconfig doesn't have strict set of options.

Comment: What infinite number? What drugs? Are you nuts? Thats what I need, but its for C++: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options.html It has support for both: config file and command line options.